# Concat function not available in office 2016 professional

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I'm working on a spreadsheet that I created on a different machine with an install of office 2016 version 1701. I'm running 2016 professional version 1707.

Many of the new functions won't work, for example Concat.

I've tried updating my install but it appears to have the most recent updates.

Any ideas why I wouldn't have access to the most recently released functions?

Comment: Do you have an Office 365 subscription?

Comment: @TimWilliams No, I believe this is a standalone version.

Comment: @TimWilliams So I got my copy through a home use license with my employer. It looks like my copy isn't eligible for the shiny new features. Sad.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CONCAT-function-9b1a9a3f-94ff-41af-9736-694cbd6b4ca2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those new functions are only available in subscription versions of Excel (i.e. you need an Office 365 subscription), and are not the 2016 versions. So if you want something equivalent, you've got to use a UDF. Here's a [link to a Concat UDF](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2014/11/14/string-concatenation-is-like-the-weather/) I wrote some time back. You can also no doubt find equivalent UDFs for the other new features that aren't in your non-subscription version via Google.